# LSTM - Matmul error in input while making prediction

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train an single step LSTM model using Keras. However, when I call the predict function I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #0 was expected to be a float tensor but is a double tensor [Op:MatMul] name: lstm_5/MatMul/
```

My input shape is (250, 7, 3)

Here are the configuration and summary of the model:

```
single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(7,
                                           input_shape=x_train_single.shape[-2:]))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

single_step_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 7)                 308       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 8         
=================================================================
Total params: 316
Trainable params: 316
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Kindly assist me

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward; have you tried casting the tensor to `tf.float32`?

Comment: Yes, I converted my numpy array to float32, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #0(zero-based) was expected to be a float tensor but is a double tensor \[Op:MatMul\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255431/invalidargumenterror-cannot-compute-matmul-as-input-0zero-based-was-expected)

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the solution in this (Answer) section even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the community.

The problem is the datatype of the `input`. By default `tensorflow keras` model expects `float32` but you are passing a `double`.

You can either change the dtype of the model as shown in the code below:

```
def make_model():
    net = tf.keras.Sequential()
    net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', dtype='float32'))
    net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return net
```

or Change the input to `float32`. To change the `input`: `X = X.astype('float32')`